# Selenium Webdriver - Count occurrence of visible form errors and return statement

Tags: python, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, webforms, count

This may have been covered by something else but I've been unable to find something that matches up to my scenario...I'm pretty new to selenium webdriver and Python so please excuse any 'best practice' issues in my code.

I'm trying to find a solution that counts the instance of field errors on a web form and if it is greater than or equal to 1 then the result should be a fail. If zero then a pass. In addition I would like to print to the console which field errors being presented.

I'm using xpaths stored in a dictionary for maintainability and then returning the string from the label (which is also my xpath identifier).

In addition the error messages are only presented on the fly so need to handle the exception 'NoSuchElementException'

I know what I want to achieve but can't seem to get the syntax right so every time the result is 'Pass' - I believe this is because 1 or more of my xpaths are returning the exception.

Below is a snippet of the code block I want to do the count and return the result:

```
    for key in formErrors:
    try:
        error = driver.find_element_by_xpath(formErrors[key]).text
        print(error)
        if error:
            error = "Fail"
    except exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
            error = "Pass"
```

Here is a snippet of my dictionary:

```
formErrors = {"error1": "//label[contains(text(),'Only letters or punctuation should be entered')]",
          "error2": "//label[contains(text(),'Only letters, numbers, spaces or dashes should be entered')]",
          "error3": "//label[contains(text(),'Only numbers and at least four digits should be entered')]",
          "error4": "//label[contains(text(),'Only letters should be entered')]"}
```

In addition the 'for key in formErrors' sits inside a for loop that sends inputs from a csv into the fields...and submits the form for each time the csv has a value...I don't think this is needed to answer my question but thought best to provide for insight.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - with a bit more time spent I've managed to find a solution that worked for me:

## for every key in the error dictionary submit the form and loop through and check for errors present

## and then return "Fail" if there are 1 or more errors and "Pass" if no errors present

```
for key in formErrors:
    try:
        error = driver.find_element_by_xpath(formErrors[key]).is_displayed()
        if error:
            errorCount += 1

    except exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
        excepPresent = True

if errorCount >= 1:
    formResult = "Fail"
else:
    formResult = "Pass"
```

errorCount is defined outside of the whole form loop and I also reset the errorCount after each form loop is completed.

The exception clause is in there just so my script doesn't fail over when it can't find an error from the error dictionary.